# Issue with ssrs parameter

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder, msbi

I have 5 bookmarks in my report,let us assume i have clicked run, then gone 5th page or 5th bookmark ,from there if i filter any values in parameter, the report refreshing and going to first bookmark, how to make stay it in only same bookmark

Comment: You can achieve this functionality with go to url where you have 5 report of different section and when you click it will redirect to another report. Since bookmark is part of report whenever you alter parameter the whole report got refresh because of that it comes in first page